# What is the difference between ParseFromArray and ParseFromString in Protobuf?

Tags: c++, performance, protocol-buffers

I'm going to deserialize a bulk of data(string etc) of protobuf-format, I can do it with both ParseFromArray and ParseFromString. What is the difference between these two?
Is one better in performance than the other?

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference on functionality.

If your data has already been saved in a `std::string`, you can use either function. However, if you data is saved in an array or `std::vector<char>` or other containers, you can use `ParseFromArray` to avoid creating an temporary string object.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems that for same data, if I save it as `vector<char>` and `ParseFromArray` , it'd get better performance than `string+ParseFromString` by avoiding the temporary string object. Am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. If you save it as `vector<char>`, you should use `ParseFromArray` to avoid temporary object. However, if you save it as `string`, you can call either `ParseFromArray` or `ParseFromString`, and you'll get the same performance as `vector<char>` + `ParseFromArray`.